durability of PVC windows
I am renovating my house and consider replacing the old aluminium windows with PVC windows such as these ones, due to their better thermal insulation properties. But, I am worried that PVC might be less durable then aluminium - over time it might bend, which might harm the insulation.
Is there data on PVC vs. aluminium windows e.g. 10-20 years after installation, showing their durability?

Since the failure mode of most modern windows is the sealed glass unit, and not the sash or window framing, it's a rather moot question. For me it's more about aesthetics and operation.

I still have have PVC windows from the 80s and 90s.  Besides some of seals breaking down between the glass panes and fogging, they are still in good condition.  Weather from -20F to plus 90F

PVC is pretty flexible—probably even more so than aluminum.  Glass is less so, hence the previously-mentioned glass failure mode.  Probably why PVC is so good—the PVC can flex with the movement of the house.
